# Mocha expectation on association build call failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, stub, mocha.js

I have this example:

```
# GET New
context "on get to new" do
  it "should assign cardset" do
    @profile.cardsets.expects(:build).once.returns(Factory.stub(:cardset))
    get :new
    assigns[:cardset].should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

To test this method:

```
# GET /cardsets/new
def new
  @cardset = current_user.cardsets.build
end
```

I am trying to enforce that the association is built from `current_user` to make sure the user is only creating things that belong to themselves. I am using an expectation very similarly to ensure they are calling `find` from the `current_user` object and it works find, but when running the above example I get:

```
6)
Mocha::ExpectationError in 'CardsetsController for a logged in user on get to new should assign cardset'
not all expectations were satisfied
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked: [#<Cardset:0x102eaa8c8>, #<Cardset:0x102e12438>].build(any_parameters)
satisfied expectations:
- allowed any number of times, not yet invoked: ApplicationController.require_user(any_parameters)
- allowed any number of times, already invoked twice: #<CardsetsController:0x1030849c8>.current_user(any_parameters)

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_app/spec/controllers/cardsets_controller_spec.rb:32:
```

Comment: I think that @profile from your test is not the same object at current_user in your controller. Could you show us the code used to set @profile?

Comment: `@profile = @cardset.profile` and `controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(@profile)` in a `before(:each)` call in the test. As I said I have another expectation similar that expects for `find` to be called off of `current_user` and this is exactly how I handle that case which passes.

Comment: Something new that should be mentioned, I just tried writing a test with this `@profile.cardsets.expects(:find).once.returns(@cardset)` which is the exact same as my `find_by_id` expectation and this doesn't work, so it seems this only works with the dynamic finder methods provided.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? Did my answer help? If not - can you post the solution for anybody with the same problem in the future? :)

Comment: Hey, you're a 10K user now... you should probably add accepts or your own solution to your questions now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You add the expectation to @profile *after* you've stubbed the function that returns it from current_user. Probably what you need to do is this:

```
# GET New
context "on get to new" do
  it "should assign cardset" do
    @profile.cardsets.expects(:build).once.returns(Factory.stub(:cardset))
    controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(@profile)
    get :new
    assigns[:cardset].should_not be_nil
  end
end
```